# Missing key point on calculate the area of a triangle

Tags: java

```
import javabook.*;


class Triangle
{
    // DATA
    //............................................................

    //Private Variables
        private double theBase;
        private double theHeight;
        private double theArea;                                     //base and height = Area is enough calculation

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    //............................................................  // same name as the class and the file name
    public Triangle()                                               
    {
        this.theBase=0;
        this.theHeight=0;
        this.theArea=0;
    }

    public Triangle( OutputBox oBox, MainWindow mWindow )           
    {
        this.theBase=0;
        this.theHeight=0;                                           this.theArea=0;                                             //This is a proof that the area of any triangle is 1/2 b x h’ of a base and height and the ‘area of a triangle is half of the base times the height’.
    }                                           


    public void calculateArea ()        
    {                                                                                              
        InputBox iBox = new InputBox(mWindow);
        this.theBase = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the length of the base of the triangle ");
        this.theHeight = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the height of the triangle");
        computeArea();
        oBox.println(" The area of a triangle of base : " + this.theBase+ " and height : " + this.theHeight +" is equal to : "+ this.theArea );
    }

    // METHODS - behaviours
    //............................................................
    public void computeArea()
    {
        this.theArea = (this.theBase / 2 ) * this.theHeight;        
                                                            }                                                               

    // METHODS - gets (accessors)  and sets (mutators)
    //............................................................

    //length
    public void setThebase(double base)
    {
           this.theBase= base;
    }

    public double getTheBase()
    {
           return(this.theBase);
    }

    //breath
    public void setTheHeight(double height)
    {
           this.theHeight= height;
    }

    public double getTheHeight()
    {
           return(this.theHeight);
    }

    //area
    public double getTheArea()
    {
           return(this.theArea);
    }
}
```

I've something missing on or above **this.theBase = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the length of the base of the triangle ");** Can anyone point it out please of what I've left it out? Be gentle as I'm learning java and bound to make mistakes.

This is a revised error messages after fixing a bogus { character:

```
]./Triangle.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable mWindow
location: class Triangle
        InputBox iBox = new InputBox(mWindow);
                                     ^
./Triangle.java:46: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable oBox
location: class Triangle
        oBox.println(" The area of a triangle of base : " + this.theBase+ " and height : " + this.theHeight +" is equal to : "+ this.theArea );
```

Updated 4 errors:

```
./Triangle.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable oBox
location: class Triangle
        this.oBox = oBox;
            ^
./Triangle.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable mWindow
location: class Triangle
        this.mWindow = mWindow;                                     //This is a proof that the area of any triangle is 1/2 b x h’ of a base and height and the ‘area of a triangle is half of the base times the height’.
            ^
./Triangle.java:47: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable mwindow
location: class Triangle
        InputBox iBox = new InputBox(mwindow);
                                     ^
./Triangle.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable oBox
location: class Triangle
        oBox.println(" The area of a triangle of base : " + this.theBase+ " and height : " + this.theHeight +" is equal to : "+ this.theArea );
        ^
Note: App.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors
            ^
```

Comment: "something missing" - do you get any error messages? If so, post them please.

Comment: I've added error messages as above.

Comment: Missing a semicolon after `this.theHeight=0` (in addition to other errors mentioned).

Comment: Turn your Triangle into a `Class` and make a new instance of it. Perform your calculations. Then set its' base, height, and area.

Comment: Do you mean this.theHeight = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the height of the triangle");

Comment: I've never seen these classes...

Comment: No, where you initialize it on line 4, you're missing a `;`. Computers tend not to be on the forgiving side.

Comment: It looks to me that, in addition to the missing semicolon, you have a bogus `}` character.  After that, I haven't checked.

Comment: @hd1. YES, its bogus { character. Now I'm getting there...

Comment: I've updated the full code as above and line 42 and 46 are errors still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All code after the first `}` doesn't belong to a method, so...you need to make one. Something like this:

```
  public Triangle( OutputBox oBox, MainWindow mWindow ) {
    this.theBase=0;
    this.theHeight=0
    this.theArea=0;                                         
  }
  public void calculateArea() {                                           
    InputBox iBox = new InputBox(mWindow);
    this.theBase = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the length of the base of the triangle ");
    this.theHeight = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the height of the triangle");
    computeArea();
    oBox.println(" The area of a triangle of base : " + this.theBase+ " and height : " + this.theHeight +" is equal to : "+ this.theArea  );
  }
}
```

Then you can just call `calculateArea()` after you make a `Triangle` object.

Let me know if you have any questions or problems.

---

Regarding your other errors, they're because you're not storing the values of `mWindow` and `oBox`. Change:

```
  public Triangle( OutputBox oBox, MainWindow mWindow )           
    {
        this.theBase=0;
        this.theHeight=0;
        this.theArea=0;
        //This is a proof that the area of any triangle is 1/2 b x h’ of a base and height and the ‘area of a triangle is half of the base times the height’.
    }
```

to

```
  public Triangle( OutputBox oBox, MainWindow mWindow )           
    {
        this.theBase=0;
        this.theHeight=0;
        this.theArea=0;
        this.oBox = oBox;
        this.mWindow = mWindow;
        //This is a proof that the area of any triangle is 1/2 b x h’ of a base and height and the ‘area of a triangle is half of the base times the height’.
    }
```

and add  `oBox` and `mWindow` in with your private variables.

Note that you will receive a runtime error if the constructor above is not used.

---

```
import javabook.*;


class Triangle
{
    // DATA
    //............................................................

    //Private Variables
        private double theBase;
        private double theHeight;
        private double theArea;                                     //base and height = Area is enough calculation
        private OutputBox oBox;
        private MainWindow mWindow;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    //............................................................  // same name as the class and the file name

    public Triangle( OutputBox oBox, MainWindow mWindow )           
    {
        this.theBase=0;
        this.theHeight=0;
        this.theArea=0;                                             //This is a proof that the area of any triangle is 1/2 b x h’ of a base and height and the ‘area of a triangle is half of the base times the height’.
        this.oBox = oBox;
        this.mWindow = mWindow;
    }                                           


    public void calculateArea ()        
    {                                                                                              
        InputBox iBox = new InputBox(this.mWindow);
        this.theBase = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the length of the base of the triangle ");
        this.theHeight = iBox.getDouble("Please enter the height of the triangle");
        computeArea();
        this.oBox.println(" The area of a triangle of base : " + this.theBase+ " and height : " + this.theHeight +" is equal to : "+ this.theArea );
    }

    // METHODS - behaviours
    //............................................................
    public void computeArea()
    {
        this.theArea = (this.theBase / 2 ) * this.theHeight;        
                                                            }                                                               

    // METHODS - gets (accessors)  and sets (mutators)
    //............................................................

    //length
    public void setThebase(double base)
    {
           this.theBase = base;
    }

    public double getTheBase()
    {
           return(this.theBase);
    }

    //breath
    public void setTheHeight(double height)
    {
           this.theHeight= height;
    }

    public double getTheHeight()
    {
           return(this.theHeight);
    }

    //area
    public double getTheArea()
    {
           return(this.theArea);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've called getTheArea. It is ok to call getTheArea instead of calculateArea?

Comment: Sure, that's fine, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: computeArea() is already defined in Triangle public void computeArea()

Comment: Where do I add public void calculateArea() elsewhere?

Comment: I've updated the full code and line 42 and 46 are errors still the same.

Comment: Thanks tsm I've tried that and I've updated 4 errors as above.

Comment: That read from /Triangle.java:36: cannot find symbol

Comment: I've just edited the file and pasted all of it in above. The key changes are: adding `oBox` and `mWindow` as private variables and removing the `Triangle()` constructor (since it is required for `oBox` and `mWindow` to be set).